# What's the right way to automatically update WEB-INF/lib directory when pom.xml/maven project dependencies are changed frequently?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ integrated with Tomcat maintaining a Maven project.
Occasionally the project structure changes and new JARs are being added and/or their versions keep changing, the changes are left out of the WEB-INF/lib.
In order to maintain a correct setup, I have to add them manually in the module structure to run Tomcat correctly. This happens a lot!

Can this be automated?

[Manually adding missing JARs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap6CX.png)

EDIT:

After watching *Eric Green's* response I did some experimenting:

The project is a parent/child project with multiple poms in it's children.
After playing around with the pom.xml of the project and modifying the main **`<packaging>jar</packaging>`** to **`<packaging>war</packaging>`** I was able to make IntelliJ to automatically include everything it needs in WEB-INF/lib , I had to do more several modifications to fix the project but eventually this was the main issue. Otherwise I had to manually specify the needed dependencies in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: There should be no need to do anything manually if you used the maven war output instead of having IntelliJ replicate the effort of Maven.

Comment: `Can this be automated?`. Well maven does it already. Use its pom.xml and commands to do your build-test-clean-pachage etc.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how the dropdown in the top toolbar in the image below has a Tomcat icon. This configuration automatically builds a standard web application, part of which of course being the placing of necessary dependencies into the WEB-INF/lib folder of the generated *.WAR archive (see the JARs inside WEB-INF/lib under the target directory in the image below). These were all placed there automatically by Maven during the "package" phase. See the steps at the bottom (below the screenshots) to ensure this occurs correctly.

[image: Tomcat Web Application]

Below is another screenshot showing the Run/Debug configuration for a Tomcat application. Maven is actually doing all the real work of assembling dependencies into a correct WAR archive, but IntelliJ is assisting in the management and deployment of the artifacts to the configured local Tomcat server.

[image]

So, to do this for yourself:

1. Set the packaging in your project's pom.xml file as "war"
2. Go to Run > Edit Configurations
3. Click the plus sign '+' and click Tomcat Server > Local
4. Fill in the dialog that pops up as directed
5. Run your Maven build ("clean install", or whatever you fancy)
6. Start Tomcat with your new Run/Debug configuration created in steps 3 and 4